# Confidence Intervals for a relative risk where i lack the underlying data

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, robust, relative-risk

I have two estimated rates and their 95% confidence intervals but not the underlying data.  I take the ratio of the two to get a relative risk, but how do I determine the 95% confidence intervals for that relative risk?

Example:  At baseline I have an estimated rate of 38.3 (95% CI, 36.0-40.8) and in the study group I have an estimated rate of 45.2 (95% CI, 43.2-47.2).  The relative risk is 1.18, but what are the 95% confidence limits.  I do not have the underlying data upon which the rates were calculated.

Comment: Can you simulate?

Comment: Since you do not have anything but the point estimate and the confidence interval, you could build a normal approximation to the distributions of $\hat{p_1}$ and $\hat{p_2}$ and check by simulation the behaviour of the resulting ratio.

Comment: What sample sizes are involved?

Answer (score 2):

So there are methods for propagating error through arithmetic opperations that are used in many areas of science. (for example look at [this.](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Analytical_Chemistry/Quantifying_Nature/Significant_Digits/Propagation_of_Error))

As the relative risk is

$$R = \frac{X}{Y}, \text{with std. of } \sigma_x , \sigma_y$$

We are interested in error through the divisor operator which is

$$\sigma_R = R\sqrt{\big(\frac{\sigma_x}{X}\big)^2 + \big(\frac{\sigma_y}{Y}\big)^2}$$

However, if X and Y are gaussian distributed R will not be.

Edit:

**Example**

> Example: At baseline I have an estimated rate of 38.3 (95% CI, 36.0-40.8) and in the study group I have an estimated rate of 45.2 (95% CI, 43.2-47.2). The relative risk is 1.18, but what are the 95% confidence limits. I do not have the underlying data upon which the rates were calculated.

$$R = 1.18$$

95% confidence interval is roughly $2\sigma$ on either side, so $\sigma_b = 1.25$ and $\sigma_s = 1$. So then

$$\sigma_R = 1.18\sqrt{\big(\frac{1.25}{38.3}\big)^2 + \big(\frac{1}{45.2}\big)^2}$$

$$\sigma_R = 0.053$$

So the relative risk is approximately $1.18\pm0.1$ with 95% confidence.

Comment: PS This assumes independence between measurements

Answer (score 1):

An additional approach would be to assume that the sampling distribution of log relative risk is normally distributed. Although the same is true for the relative risk, the sample size needs to be larger for this fact to be helpful in practice. In fact, it is often the case that the most commonly used formula for relative risk confidence intervals (Wald CIs) makes this assumption about the log relative risk. Using OP's example, we have:

```R
set.seed(12345) # For reproducibility
rr.a <- 38.3
rr.b <- 45.2
ci.a <- c(36, 40.8)
ci.b <- c(43.2, 47.2)
```

We can calculate the standard deviations on the log scale. They would be the difference between the log confidence intervals divided by about 4. `qnorm` is the quantile function of the normal distribution.

```R
l.sd.a <- diff(log(ci.a)) / qnorm(.975) / 2
l.sd.b <- diff(log(ci.b)) / qnorm(.975) / 2
```

We next assume that the log relative risks are normal with mean as the estimated log relative risk and standard deviations as the values above. We can draw a large number of samples assuming both distributions then take the difference between both samples.

```R
nboots <- 1e4
log.rr.s <- rnorm(nboots, log(rr.b), l.sd.b) - rnorm(nboots, log(rr.a), l.sd.a)
```

And for results, the exponentiated 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles:

```R
exp(quantile(log.rr.s, c(.025, .975)))
#     2.5%    97.5% 
# 1.094151 1.274278
```

In OP's specific example, it probably does not make a difference since the CIs for the RR are themselves symmetric. This is more likely when the RRs are huge numbers as in OP's example.

Comment: This is very helpful. Any way to relax the assumption of normality? I posted related questions here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380793/resampling-based-confidence-intervals-for-relative-excess-risk-due-to-interactio and here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380818/likelihood-based-confidence-intervals-for-ratio-of-risk-ratios. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Krantz the assumption of normality on the log scale is readily believable at modest sample sizes. If all you have is the information you provided, I do not know how you can relax the normality assumption. You can assume an alternative distribution maybe ... I will look at the additional questions.

Comment: @Krantz one question, why is the rate in your question above 1?

Comment: @Krantz I was asking about the question I have already answered. with rates like 38 and 40.

Comment: @Krantz a rate is a count of the number of events divided by the all events, right? So was curious as to why the rate is not between 0 and 1.

Comment: In epidemiology, strictly speaking the true rate is the incidence rate, which is computed by dividing the total number of health-related events that occurred by the total exposure time at risk for the group. The ratio of two rates (rate ratio) can be >1 if the second rate is greater than the first rate. That is why your answer is perfect.

Comment: @Krantz Thanks. So the denominator for the rate is time-interval.

Comment: Yes, @Heteroskedastic Jim. The unit of rate is number of events per person-year.  So the denominator is the number of person-time at risk, and the numerator is the number of events. I answered a question about that here: stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376302/